# Easiest way to parse json format response data in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Example,

From the server-side it sends the json format data like this,

```
[{"id":3,"firstname":"Hansik","lastname":"Lee","email":"hansik.lee@access-company.com"},{"id":179,"firstname":"hansik1","lastname":"hansik1","email":"hansik1@hansik1.com"},{"id":193,"firstname":"hansik","lastname":"hansik","email":"ikebi77@gmail.com"}]
```

what is the easiest way to print each key and value in jQUery?

is there a good library or api?

tried to use jQuery.parseJSON, but i think it supports very easy type of format.

```
success: function (result) {
                //do somthing here
                    //window.alert(result);
                    window.alert(jQuery.parseJSON(result));
                },
```

and it only shows like `[Object object], [Object object], [Object object]`

Comment: You get an array of objects. Hence the result of the alert is an array.toString representation. Just iterate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to parse it, by passing the `dataType: 'json'` to the ajax request you jQuery will do it and give you a parsed object as the response

to alert use a json object first you need to stringify it. You can use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to do it(for old browsers include [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js))

```
window.alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

For debugging purpose it is much better to use browser console like

```
console.log(result)
```

Use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) like

```
$.each(result, function(idx, obj){
    console.log(obj.id);//or firstname or any othe property
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. ok after stringfigy, how can i get the key and valeu?

Comment: Thank you so much:). btw, stringify makes an undefined result, but parsejson shows the result. so i just changed it

Answer (score 0):

you can have`dataType:json`, and your server side should capable of converting you object to json representation , use json processor for this task, with the below code you will get your response in json format, use `$.each` to iterate through

```
 ajax{
      dataType: "json";

      success function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            data[index].id;

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var arr=[{"id":3,"firstname":"Hansik","lastname":"Lee","email":"hansik.lee@access-company.com"},{"id":179,"firstname":"hansik1","lastname":"hansik1","email":"hansik1@hansik1.com"},{"id":193,"firstname":"hansik","lastname":"hansik","email":"ikebi77@gmail.com"}]
var output=''
for (var i in arr)
{
  output+='<tr><td>'+arr[i].id+'</td><td>'+arr[i].firstname+'</td><td>'+arr[i].lastname+'</td><td>'+arr[i].email+'</td></tr>';
}
$('#s_d').empty().append(output);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zq5R4/4/)